# How can I print the GL Impact in Advanced PDF/HTML Template?

Tags: netsuite

This is the GL Impact look like, I need to get and print the "Account, Amount(Debit) and Amount(Credit) to Advanced PDF/HTML Template.

[image: image is here]

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the document?  If it is via script, you might be able to get the GL Impact via search and add the search results as an object.  The you can loop through the results like you would with item sublist.